# How to add wiki functionality to a joomla site.?

Tags: joomla, wiki

Any native wiki extension on joomla?
Or shall i go for doku-wiki or media-wiki integration or any other recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MindTouch](http://developer.mindtouch.com/) (aka Deki Wiki) is an excellent open source wiki which supports [Joomla authentication](http://developer.mindtouch.com/index.php?title=MindTouch_Deki/Authentication/JoomlaAuthentication).

Answer (score 1):

The Jwiki extension does a good job of offering an easy way to setup a Mediawiki-based solution. You should try it out.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/wiki-integration/12982

Answer (score 0):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/3723/details
I have found this. Any opinions. Has someone tested it on a live site.